# Writing a raw opus buffer to a file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, discord, buffer, voice, opus

I'm working on Discord voice and I made voice receiver, but I can't seem to be able to write the audio buffer to a file to be able to play it. Here's my code:

```js
stopRecording() {
    this.recording = false;
    let output = Buffer.concat(this.recordedBuffers);
    fs.writeFileSync('./out.opus', output.toString());
    this.recordedBuffers = [];
    console.log('done');
};
```

The file gets created but it is unplayable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth confirming that `recordedBuffers` contains Ogg Opus file data. The first 32 bytes should show file header data indicating this is an Ogg, Webm, or Mp4 container.  Once the mime-type is confirmed, the file extension can be changed from `.opus` if needed:

```js
/*  .opus = 'OggS ... Opus'
 *  .webm = '... webm ...'
 *  .mp4  = '... mp4 ...'
 *  .wav  = '... WAVE ...'
 */
new TextDecoder().decode(concatenatedBuffers.slice(0, 32))
```

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) could also inspect the downloaded file:

```sh
$ ffprobe audio.opus 

Input #0, ogg, from 'audio.opus':
  Duration: 00:06:00.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 99 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
```